# Xamarin.Forms - Adding appointment to syncfusion schedule from another file

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am trying to add appointment to my syncfusion schedule (SfSchedule) from another file. However it´s giving me this error message: "***CS0122 MainPage.ScheduleDay' is inaccessible due to its protection level    School_schedule***" The schedule form first file cannot be accessed by second file. Spent several hours looking for solution :/ Can anyone please help?

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfaal.jpg)

My code:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
        <syncfusion:SfSchedule.DayViewSettings>
            <syncfusion:DayViewSettings
                NonWorkingHoursTimeSlotColor="White">
            </syncfusion:DayViewSettings>
        </syncfusion:SfSchedule.DayViewSettings>

        <syncfusion:SfSchedule.SelectionView>
            <Button 
                x:Name="Button_Open_Add_Event"
                BackgroundColor="Orange"
                Text="+New Event"
                TextColor="White"
                Clicked ="Open_Add_Event"/>
        </syncfusion:SfSchedule.SelectionView>
    </syncfusion:SfSchedule>
</StackLayout>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
 public async void Open_Add_Event(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        AddEvent Popup_Open_AddEvent = new AddEvent();

        await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(Popup_Open_AddEvent);
    }
```

**AddEvent.xaml**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>

        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

        <DatePicker 
            x:Name="Date_Add_Event"
        />

        <TimePicker
            x:Name="Time_Add_Event"
        />

        <Label x:Name="Test"></Label>

        <Button 
            Clicked="Button_CreateEvent"
            Text="Create"
        />

        <Button 
            Clicked="Button_BacktomainPage" 
            Text="Cancel"
        />

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**AddEvent.xaml.cs**

```
public void Button_CreateEvent (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        
        DateTime Date_from = Date_Add_Event.Date + Time_Add_Event.Time;

        Test.Text = Date_from.ToString();

        // Creating an instance for schedule appointment collection
        ScheduleAppointmentCollection scheduleAppointmentCollection = new ScheduleAppointmentCollection();
        //Adding schedule appointment in schedule appointment collection 
        scheduleAppointmentCollection.Add(new ScheduleAppointment()
        {
            StartTime = new DateTime (2021, 02, 11, 10, 00, 00),
            EndTime = new DateTime(2021, 02, 11, 12,00,00),
            Subject = "Meeting",
            Location = "Hutchison road",
        }) ;

        //Adding schedule appointment col+lection to DataSource of SfSchedule
          MainPage.ScheduleDay.DataSource = scheduleAppointmentCollection;

    }

    

    public void Button_BacktomainPage (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have prepared the sample as per given information and checked the reported scenario from our end. We regret to inform you that we could not replicate the reported scenario from our side.  It's working as expected.

View

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScheduleXamarin"
             xmlns:schedule="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms"
             x:Class="ScheduleXamarin.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
       <schedule:SfSchedule x:Name="schedule"
                                 DataSource="{Binding ListOfMeeting}"
                                 ScheduleView="DayView" CellDoubleTapped="Schedule_CellDoubleTapped"
                                 Margin="0">
                <schedule:SfSchedule.AppointmentMapping>
                    <schedule:ScheduleAppointmentMapping
                        ColorMapping="Color"
                        EndTimeMapping="To"
                        IsAllDayMapping="IsAllDay"
                        StartTimeMapping="From"
                        SubjectMapping="EventName"
                        MinHeightMapping="MinimumHeight"
                        StartTimeZoneMapping="StartTimeZone"
                        EndTimeZoneMapping="EndTimeZone"/>
                </schedule:SfSchedule.AppointmentMapping>
                <schedule:SfSchedule.BindingContext>
                    <local:AppointmentEditorViewModel/>
            </schedule:SfSchedule.BindingContext>
        </schedule:SfSchedule>
    </Grid>
         </ContentPage.Content>
   </ContentPage>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:schedulexamarin="clr-namespace:ScheduleXamarin"
             x:Class="ScheduleXamarin.View.EditorLayout">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <schedulexamarin:EditorLayoutViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
   
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="editorLayout">
            <ScrollView x:Name="editorScrollView">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Grid
        x:Name="eventName_layout"
        Padding="20,10,20,0"
        HeightRequest="40"
        VerticalOptions="Start">
                        <Entry
            x:Name="eventNameText"
            HeightRequest="40"
            TextColor="Black" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid
        x:Name="organizer_layout"
        Padding="20,20,20,0"
        HeightRequest="40"
        VerticalOptions="Start">
                        <Entry
            x:Name="organizerText"
            HeightRequest="40"
            TextColor="Black" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid
        x:Name="startTimeLabel_layout"
        Padding="20,10,20,0"
        HeightRequest="20"
        VerticalOptions="Start">
                        <Label
            Font="15"
            Text="From"
            TextColor="Gray" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid
        x:Name="StartdateTimePicker_layout"
        Padding="20,0,20,0"
        VerticalOptions="Start">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid
            x:Name="start_datepicker_layout"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HeightRequest="50"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            WidthRequest="20">
                            <DatePicker x:Name="startDate_picker" HeightRequest="40" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid
            x:Name="start_timepicker_layout"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HeightRequest="50"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            WidthRequest="20">
                            <TimePicker x:Name="startTime_picker" HeightRequest="40" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="White" 
                Padding="20,0,20,0"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" x:Name="startTimeZoneLabel" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center" 
                    Text="Start Time Zone" 
                    FontSize="15" TextColor="Gray" />
                        <Picker x:Name="startTimeZonePicker" Grid.Row="1" 
                        VerticalOptions="Center" 
                        SelectedIndex="0"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        </Picker>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid
        x:Name="endTimeLabel_layout"
        Padding="20,10,20,0"
        HeightRequest="20"
        VerticalOptions="Start">
                        <Label
            Font="15"
            HeightRequest="20"
            Text="To"
            TextColor="Gray" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid
        x:Name="EndDateTimePicker_layout"
        Padding="20,0,20,0"
        VerticalOptions="Start">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid
            x:Name="end_datepicker_layout"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HeightRequest="50"
            VerticalOptions="Start">
                            <DatePicker
                x:Name="endDate_picker"
                Grid.Column="0"
                HeightRequest="50"
                VerticalOptions="Start" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid
            x:Name="end_timepicker_layout"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HeightRequest="50"
            VerticalOptions="Start">
                            <TimePicker
                x:Name="endTime_picker"
                HeightRequest="50"
                VerticalOptions="Start" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="White" 
                Padding="20,0,20,0"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" x:Name="endTimeZoneLabel" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center" 
                    Text="End Time Zone" 
                    FontSize="15" TextColor="Gray" />
                        <Picker x:Name="endTimeZonePicker" Grid.Row="1" 
                        VerticalOptions="Center" 
                        SelectedIndex="0"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        </Picker>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid
        x:Name="allDayGrid"
        Padding="20,10,20,0"
        VerticalOptions="Start">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label x:Name="allDayLabel"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Font="15"
            Text="All Day"
            TextColor="Gray"
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Padding="20,0,0,0">
                            <Switch
                x:Name="switchAllDay"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            <Grid x:Name="editorButtons" BackgroundColor="White"
        VerticalOptions="Start">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid x:Name="cancelButtonGrid"
            Grid.Column="0">
                    <Button
                x:Name="cancelButton"
                Text="Cancel"
                TextColor="#3B3B3B"
                WidthRequest="100" />
                </Grid>
                <Grid  x:Name="saveButtonGrid"
            Grid.Column="1">
                    <Button
                x:Name="saveButton"
                Text="Save"
                TextColor="White"
                WidthRequest="100" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

ViewModel

```
namespace ScheduleXamarin
{
    #region AppointmentEditorViewModel
    public class AppointmentEditorViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// current day meetings 
        /// </summary>
        private List<string> currentDayMeetings;

        /// <summary>
        /// minimum time meetings
        /// </summary>
        private List<string> minTimeMeetings;

        /// <summary>
        /// color collection
        /// </summary>
        private List<Color> colorCollection;

        /// <summary>
        /// list of meeting
        /// </summary>
        private ObservableCollection<Meeting> listOfMeeting;

        /// <summary>
        /// header label value
        /// </summary>
        private string headerLabelValue = DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("MMMM yyyy");

        #region ScheduleType

        /// <summary>
        /// schedule type collection
        /// </summary>
        private ObservableCollection<ScheduleTypeClass> scheduleTypeCollection = new ObservableCollection<ScheduleTypeClass>();

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AppointmentEditorViewModel" /> class.
        /// </summary>
        public AppointmentEditorViewModel()
        {
            this.ListOfMeeting = new ObservableCollection<Meeting>();
            this.InitializeDataForBookings();
            this.BookingAppointments();
            this.AddScheduleType();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Property changed event handler
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #region ListOfMeeting

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets list of meeting
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<Meeting> ListOfMeeting
        {
            get
            {
                return this.listOfMeeting;
            }

            set
            {
                this.listOfMeeting = value;
                this.RaiseOnPropertyChanged("ListOfMeeting");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region HeaderLabelValue

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets header label value
        /// </summary>
        public string HeaderLabelValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.headerLabelValue;
            }

            set
            {
                this.headerLabelValue = value;
                this.RaiseOnPropertyChanged("HeaderLabelValue");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets schedule type collection
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<ScheduleTypeClass> ScheduleTypeCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return this.scheduleTypeCollection;
            }

            set
            {
                this.scheduleTypeCollection = value;
                this.RaiseOnPropertyChanged("ScheduleTypeCollection");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// method for adding schedule types
        /// </summary>
        private void AddScheduleType()
        {
            this.ScheduleTypeCollection.Add(new ScheduleTypeClass() { ScheduleType = "Day view" });
            this.ScheduleTypeCollection.Add(new ScheduleTypeClass() { ScheduleType = "Week view" });
            this.ScheduleTypeCollection.Add(new ScheduleTypeClass() { ScheduleType = "Work week view" });
            this.ScheduleTypeCollection.Add(new ScheduleTypeClass() { ScheduleType = "Month view" });
            this.scheduleTypeCollection.Add(new ScheduleTypeClass() { ScheduleType = "Timeline view" });
        }

        #region BookingAppointments

        /// <summary>
        /// Method for booking appointments.
        /// </summary>
        private void BookingAppointments()
        {
            Random randomTime = new Random();
            List<Point> randomTimeCollection = this.GettingTimeRanges();

            DateTime date;
            DateTime dateFrom = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
            DateTime dateTo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
            DateTime dateRangeStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);
            DateTime dateRangeEnd = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);

            for (date = dateFrom; date < dateTo; date = date.AddDays(1))
            {
                if ((DateTime.Compare(date, dateRangeStart) > 0) && (DateTime.Compare(date, dateRangeEnd) < 0))
                {
                    for (int additionalAppointmentIndex = 0; additionalAppointmentIndex < 3; additionalAppointmentIndex++)
                    {
                        Meeting meeting = new Meeting();
                        int hour = randomTime.Next((int)randomTimeCollection[additionalAppointmentIndex].X, (int)randomTimeCollection[additionalAppointmentIndex].Y);
                        meeting.From = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, hour, 0, 0);
                        meeting.To = meeting.From.AddHours(1);
                        meeting.EventName = this.currentDayMeetings[randomTime.Next(9)];
                        meeting.Color = this.colorCollection[randomTime.Next(9)];
                        meeting.IsAllDay = false;
                        meeting.StartTimeZone = string.Empty;
                        meeting.EndTimeZone = string.Empty;
                        this.ListOfMeeting.Add(meeting);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Meeting meeting = new Meeting();
                    meeting.From = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, randomTime.Next(9, 11), 0, 0);
                    meeting.To = meeting.From.AddDays(2).AddHours(1);
                    meeting.EventName = this.currentDayMeetings[randomTime.Next(9)];
                    meeting.Color = this.colorCollection[randomTime.Next(9)];
                    meeting.IsAllDay = true;
                    meeting.StartTimeZone = string.Empty;
                    meeting.EndTimeZone = string.Empty;
                    this.ListOfMeeting.Add(meeting);
                }
            }

            // Minimum Height Meetings
            DateTime minDate;
            DateTime minDateFrom = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
            DateTime minDateTo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);

            for (minDate = minDateFrom; minDate < minDateTo; minDate = minDate.AddDays(1))
            {
                Meeting meeting = new Meeting();
                meeting.From = new DateTime(minDate.Year, minDate.Month, minDate.Day, randomTime.Next(9, 18), 30, 0);
                meeting.To = meeting.From;
                meeting.EventName = this.minTimeMeetings[randomTime.Next(0, 4)];
                meeting.Color = this.colorCollection[randomTime.Next(0, 10)];
                meeting.StartTimeZone = string.Empty;
                meeting.EndTimeZone = string.Empty;

                // Setting Mininmum Appointment Height for Schedule Appointments
                if (Device.RuntimePlatform == "Android")
                {
                    meeting.MinimumHeight = 50;
                }
                else
                {
                    meeting.MinimumHeight = 25;
                }

                this.ListOfMeeting.Add(meeting);
            }
        }

        #endregion BookingAppointments

        #region GettingTimeRanges

        /// <summary>
        /// Method for get timing range.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>return time collection</returns>
        private List<Point> GettingTimeRanges()
        {
            List<Point> randomTimeCollection = new List<Point>();
            randomTimeCollection.Add(new Point(9, 11));
            randomTimeCollection.Add(new Point(12, 14));
            randomTimeCollection.Add(new Point(15, 17));

            return randomTimeCollection;
        }

        #endregion GettingTimeRanges

        #region InitializeDataForBookings

        /// <summary>
        /// Method for initialize data bookings.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeDataForBookings()
        {
            this.currentDayMeetings = new List<string>();
            this.currentDayMeetings.Add("General Meeting");
            this.currentDayMeetings.Add("Plan Execution");
            this.currentDayMeetings.Add("Project Plan");
            this.currentDayMeetings.Add("Consulting");
            this.currentDayMeetings.Add("Performance Check");
            this.currentDayMeetings.Add("Yoga Therapy");
            this.currentDayMeetings.Add("Plan Execution");
            this.currentDayMeetings.Add("Project Plan");
            this.currentDayMeetings.Add("Consulting");
            this.currentDayMeetings.Add("Performance Check");

            // MinimumHeight Appointment Subjects
            this.minTimeMeetings = new List<string>();
            this.minTimeMeetings.Add("Work log alert");
            this.minTimeMeetings.Add("Birthday wish alert");
            this.minTimeMeetings.Add("Task due date");
            this.minTimeMeetings.Add("Status mail");
            this.minTimeMeetings.Add("Start sprint alert");

            this.colorCollection = new List<Color>();
            this.colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FF339933"));
            this.colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FF00ABA9"));
            this.colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FFE671B8"));
            this.colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FF1BA1E2"));
            this.colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FFD80073"));
            this.colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FFA2C139"));
            this.colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FFA2C139"));
            this.colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FFD80073"));
            this.colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FF339933"));
            this.colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FFE671B8"));
            this.colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FF00ABA9"));
        }

        #endregion InitializeDataForBookings

        #region Property Changed Event

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoke method when property changed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">property name</param>
        private void RaiseOnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion
    }
    #endregion

    #region ScheduleTypeClass

    /// <summary>
    /// Schedule Type Class
    /// </summary>
    public class ScheduleTypeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region ScheduleType

        /// <summary>
        /// schedule type
        /// </summary>
        private string scheduleType = " ";

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets schedule types
        /// </summary>
        public string ScheduleType
        {
            get
            {
                return this.scheduleType;
            }

            set
            {
                this.scheduleType = value;
                this.RaiseOnPropertyChanged("ScheduleType");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// property changed event handler
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoke method when property changed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">property name</param>
        private void RaiseOnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

namespace ScheduleXamarin
{
    internal class EditorLayoutViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// method for appointment modified
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Schedule Appointment Modified Event Args</param>
        public virtual void OnAppointmentModified(ScheduleAppointmentModifiedEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<ScheduleAppointmentModifiedEventArgs> handler = this.AppointmentModified;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event handler
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<ScheduleAppointmentModifiedEventArgs> AppointmentModified;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// schedule appointment modified event args
    /// </summary>
    public class ScheduleAppointmentModifiedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets appointment
        /// </summary>
        public Meeting Appointment
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets is modified value
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsModified
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
namespace ScheduleXamarin
{
    [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    public class Meeting
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets event name
        /// </summary>
        public string EventName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets organizer
        /// </summary>
        public string Organizer { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets contact ID
        /// </summary>
        public string ContactID { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets capacity
        /// </summary>
        public int Capacity { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets date
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime From { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets date
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime To { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets color
        /// </summary>
        public Color Color { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets minimum height
        /// </summary>
        public double MinimumHeight { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets all day
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsAllDay { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets start time zone
        /// </summary>
        public string StartTimeZone { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets end time zone
        /// </summary>
        public string EndTimeZone { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<object> Resources { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employees : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string name;
        private object id;
        private Color color;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        public object ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }

        public Color Color
        {
            get { return color; }
            set
            {
                color = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Color");
            }
        }

        public string Image { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```